# Why do I keep getting the nosuchelementexception error?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to get multiple inputs from the user by using Scanner class. I'm using net beans and trying to run and compile my code within the net beans IDE. The program runs and compiles whenever I do not close the scanner after asking for input. But when I attempt to close the scanner after every time I asked for input I get an the `nosuchelementexception` scanner closed error. In class, we were taught to close scanner after every time we ask for input from the user. My professor does this, also while using NetBeans and his program compiles and runs every time. Like me, he also only declares scanner once and uses the same variable multiple times while asking for input from the user.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; // This allows us to use Scanner

public class GettingInput {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// ALWAYS give the user instructions. System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");

    // Create a new scanner
    Scanner keysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Specify the type of data/variable you are scanning in
    int num = keysIn.nextInt();
    // Close your scanner when you are done.
    keysIn.close();
    // ALWAYS confirm that you scanned in what you thought you did.
    System.out.println("Your int: " + num);

    // Repeat the process for a different data type
    System.out.println("---------");
    System.out.println("Enter a floating-point value:");
    keysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num2 = keysIn.nextDouble(); // note the different method
    keysIn.close();
    System.out.println("Your floating-point: " + num2);

    // Repeat it yet again
    System.out.println("---------");
    System.out.println("Now enter a string.");
    keysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = keysIn.nextLine(); // again, a different method
    keysIn.close();
    System.out.println(str);       
 }
}
```

This is code he had written, compiled and ran in class. When I try to run the same code it does not work.

I'm also using a Mac Book Pro and the latest version of Mac OS.

Comment: Don't close the `Scanner`. It's that simple.

Comment: This is what my professor expects. So it's not that simple. Why is he able to compile and run the same code?

Comment: which version of sdk are you using? does it match the number with your teachers?

Comment: jdk1.8.0_65.jdk

Comment: Your professor gave you broken code, it's that simple. Look up the Javadoc, show it to the prof. `When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.`

Comment: then there is no way your teacher could do this, since both you and your teacher are using the same version of java and exactly the same code!

be logical, ask yourself, how could even this happen? you will find your answer. 

all right, next day you meet your teacher, don't forget to tell us about the story about this. :)

Comment: Well, I know everyone else in y program uses Dr java. But would that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't work in Dr Java, Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Unix, Windows, or anything else.  The code that your professor gave you is wrong.  Simple as that.  (If it works on one of these things, then it's nothing more than luck.)

Comment: @JoeC I wouldn't call contract-breaking behavior "luck", though :)

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you closed the scanner and initiating the scanner object again. so it is better that you don't close the scanner where you know you are going to use it later again in your code, but you should do it once you are done with it.

Another thing is that, for different type of inputs you even don't need to create an entire scanner object again, you can just call appropriate methods of that scanner for your corresponding inputs type. Such that

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GettingInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keysIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = keysIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your int: " + num);

        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("Enter a floating-point value:");
        double num2 = keysIn.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println("Your floating-point: " + num2);

        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("Now enter a string.");
        String str = keysIn.next(); 
        keysIn.close();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the code of my professor. Why is he able to run and compile the same code?

Comment: is this what he gave you exactly?

Comment: Yes. I didn't modify anything. He was able to compile and run this exact code in class.